# How to reduce the size of dll/wasm compiled by aspnet/blazor?

Tags: mono, webassembly, blazor

I notice that the file size of `*.wasm` compiled by `Rust` is acceptable . However , a minimal HelloWorld compiled by `AspNet/Blazor` will take up almost 2.8MB .

```
mono.wasm       1.75MB
mscorlib.dll    1.64MB
*.dll           ....
```

If I understand correctly , the `mono.wasm` is the VM that runs in browser and runs the dll we write . Does that mean no matter what we do , we cannot make the size of files less than 1.75MB ? If not , is there a way to reduce the file size ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0 has some hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, 2.8 MBytes is quite a large payload for a 'Hello World' applications. However, Blazor is still very much an experimental technology, which is not ready for production use yet. There are numerous reasons why the generated output is so large at the moment:

Your current application runs in an interpreted mode, where the `mono.wasm` file ships the CLR to your browser, allowing it to execute your DLL. A faster, and more size efficient approach would be to use Ahead of Time Compilation (AOT) [as described in this article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2018/02/06/blazor-intro/). This would allow the compiler to strip out any library functions that are not used, giving a highly optimised output.

The features of the WebAssembly runtime itself are quite limited, future version will add [garbage collection](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/07/20/wasm-future.html) and various other capabilities that Blazor will be able to use directly. At the moment `mono.wasm` includes its own garbage collector.

The Blazor project itself has a [number of open issues](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/47) describing various optimisations which are being actively worked on. It already performs tree-shaking and various other optimisations, but this type of work takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (2021), a hello world Blazor WASM application (Visual Studio project template) downloads over 17 MB of data. When gzip is used, this got reduced to 7 MB - which is really huge if we think about the fact that no application code/logic is included yet!

But I found out that it seems the linker was not active during debugging. If we publish the application in release mode (`-c Release` switch), only necessary files were loaded. This increases the transfer size to 5.6 MB or even 2.4 MB with gzip activated. You can also see this in the size of the published folder:

```
$ dotnet publish --output publish_debug -c Debug
$ dotnet publish --output publish_release -c Release

$ du -hs publish_debug/
30M publish_debug/
$ du -hs publish_release/
11M publish_release/
```

It's still a noticeable amount of data. However, this information may help others finding this questions because of the much larger 17/7 MB shown in debug mode.

Since the question is from 2018, it may be also interested to mention that [framework caching was improved in `3.2.0-preview2`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/#improved-framework-caching). This means: The runtime and framework are stored in the browser cache after fetching them initially from the server. Since this is handled by JavaScript, no further requests are made to this files after they got cached! The server may would respond with 304 Not Modified, but it's still some overhead which we haven't any more now.

This also means that they **only** appear on the **first page load** in the network tab! If you want to measure the loading time without cache, delete the cache for those domain. This has to be done manually! Checking the *no cache* checkbox in the browser console is **not** enough, since it seems that Blazor uses the local storage with JS.